# Can't access JDBC driver through spark with AWS EMR instance

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, apache-spark

I have installed the postgresql driver package when I run spark-shell after I have ssh'ed into the EMR `spark-shell --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42`. I then import org.postgresql. I want to create a spark Dataframe object, so I try to access a table from  an s3 instance.

`sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://pathto.table.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/table?user=username&password=password","dbtable" -> "table"))`

this gives me a `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` error.

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854717/on-amazon-emr-4-0-0-setting-etc-spark-conf-spark-env-conf-is-ineffective) question with a similar problem. But I want to be able to run the driver through spark-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, (sorry, I don't have a computer to test it now) you'll need to set the driver class explicitly inside your options map.

```
sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
         Map("driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver", 
             "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://pathto.table.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/table?user=username&password=password",
             "dbtable" -> "table"))
```

PS: I'm writing this answer on my phone, please forgive the eventual typos. But I think that you get the idea.

Comment: yes thanks, I tried it and it looks like something is wrong with my version of jdbc 

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Ok that is another issue. Check the java version between your dependencies, spark and the one installed on emr